# Composition of Frobenius $n$-homomorphisms, characteristic-free?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

This question is, as so often, a crossbreed of curiosity and laziness. The
former has led me to an [interesting, but somewhat unsatisfactory paper by
Khudaverdian and Voronov
(arXiv:2002.02395v2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02395v2) and, in particular,
a strikingly beautiful theorem therein. The latter has prevented me from the
kind of source work that would answer, if not my actual question, then at
least the meta-question whether the question is new. But I feel excused by the
opinion that, even if not new, it is underexposed and deserves to be better known.

It begins with a semi-classical notion: that of a (Frobenius) $n$-homomorphism
$f:A\rightarrow B$ between two rings $A$ and $B$, with $B$ commutative. Let me
recall its definition, while generalizing it to a more natural setting.

> **Definition.** Let $A$ be a ring, and let $B$ be a commutative ring. Let
> $f:A\rightarrow B$ be any $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map.
>
> **(a)** We say that $f$ is *central* if $f\left(  aa^{\prime}\right)
> =f\left(  a^{\prime}a\right)  $ for all $a,a^{\prime}\in A$.
>
> **(b)** If $f$ is central, and if $n$ is a nonnegative integer, then we define
> the $\mathbb{Z}$-multilinear map $f_{n}:A^{n}\rightarrow B$ by
> \begin{align*}
> f_{n}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  =\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\left(
> -1\right)  ^{\sigma}\prod_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots
> ,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a cycle of }\sigma}}f\left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}
> }\cdots a_{i_{k}}\right)  ,
> \end{align*}
> where $S_{n}$ denotes the $n$-th symmetric group (of permutations of $\left\{
> 1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $), and where $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}$ denotes the
> sign of a permutation $\sigma$. Note that the right hand side here is
> well-defined, since the centrality of $f$ ensures that the value $f\left(
> a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}}\right)  $ does not depend on where we start
> indexing the cycle $c$. The map $f_{n}$ is called the *$n$-Frobenius map* of
> $f$. For instance,
> \begin{align*}
> f_{0}\left(  {}\right)    & =1;\\
> f_{1}\left(  a\right)    & =f\left(  a\right)  ;\\
> f_{2}\left(  a,b\right)    & =f\left(  a\right)  f\left(  b\right)  -f\left(
> ab\right)  ;\\
> f_{3}\left(  a,b,c\right)    & =f\left(  a\right)  f\left(  b\right)  f\left(
> c\right)  -f\left(  a\right)  f\left(  bc\right)  -f\left(  b\right)  f\left(
> ca\right)  -f\left(  c\right)  f\left(  ab\right)  +2f\left(  abc\right)  .
> \end{align*}
> Note that $f_{n}$ can also be defined recursively by
> \begin{align*}
> & f_{n}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  \\
> & =f\left(  a_{n}\right)  f_{n-1}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n-1}\right)
> \\
> & \qquad -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_{n-1}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{i-1},a_{i}a_{n}
> ,a_{i+1},a_{i+2},\ldots,a_{n-1}\right)  .
> \end{align*}
>
> **(c)** Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. We say that $f$ is an
> *$n$-homomorphism* (or *Frobenius $n$-homomorphism*) if $f$ is central and satisfies $f_{n+1}=0$ (identically). (Note that the $1$-homomorphisms
> are just the nonunital ring homomorphisms.)

This notion of an $n$-homomorphism seems to originate in [a telegraphic
article by Buchstaber and Rees (*Frobenius $k$-characters and $n$-ring
homomorphisms*, Russian Mathematical Surveys,
1997)](https://doi.org/10.1070/RM1997v052n02ABEH001788), and was developed
further in [V. M. Buchstaber, E. G. Rees, *The Gelfand map and symmetric
products*, arXiv:math/0109122v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109122v1).
Subsequently it has been studied by Khudaverdian and Voronov in papers that
include [the one referenced above](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02395v2). Alas,
all this literature only covers the case when $A$ is a commutative
$\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. I believe the general setting is more useful, since it
also covers another classical notion: that of a pseudo-character, as
considered (e.g.) in

- [Vladimir Dotsenko,
  *Pseudo-characters*](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Evdots/research/files/Pseudo-characters.pdf);
- [Sophie Morel, *Representation theory*, 2019](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Esmorel/rep_theory_notes.pdf),
  §VII.7.3,
- [Joel Bellaiche, *Ribet's lemma, generalizations, and
  pseudocharacters*](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Ejbellaic/RibetHawaii3.pdf),
- [Gaetan Chenevier, *The p-adic analytic space of pseudocharacters of a
  profinite group and pseudorepresentations over arbitrary rings*, arXiv:0809.0415v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0415v2),
- and apparently in earlier papers by Mazur, Wiles and Taylor, although in
  forms that I cannot recognize.

The connection is that a linear map $f:A\rightarrow B$ from a ring $A$ to a
commutative ring $B$ is an $n$-homomorphism if and only if the corresponding
$B$-linear map
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{f}:B\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A  & \rightarrow B,\\
b\otimes a  & \mapsto bf\left(  a\right)
\end{align*}
is a pseudocharacter of degree $n$. Conversely, a $B$-linear map
$f:A\rightarrow B$ from a $B$-algebra $A$ to its (commutative) base ring $B$
is a pseudo-character of degree $n$ if and only if it is an $n$-homomorphism.
Thus, the concept of an $n$-homomorphism and that of a pseudo-character of
degree $n$ subsume each other. Apparently the two respective communities are
mostly unaware of one another, even though both credit Frobenius for the
original idea.

I should note that the literature on both sides mostly considers the case when
$A$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, or at least when $n!$ is invertible in $A$.
This brings me to my question.

> **Question.** In full generality, is it true that the composition of an
> $n$-homomorphism with an $m$-homomorphism is an $nm$-homomorphism?
>
> That is: Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three rings, with $B$ and $C$ commutative.
> Let $f:B\rightarrow C$ be an $n$-homomorphism, and let $g:A\rightarrow B$ be
> an $m$-homomorphism. Must $f\circ g$ be an $nm$-homomorphism?

When all three rings are commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras, this is part of
Theorem 3.2 in [H. M. Khudaverdian, Th. Th. Voronov, *On the Buchstaber--Rees
theory of "Frobenius n-homomorphisms" and its generalization*
(arXiv:2002.02395v2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02395v2). I am wondering
about the general case.

For comparison, the other part of Theorem 3.2 in loc. cit. is easily
extendable to the fully general case (and I think this might be known to the
pseudo-character community):

> **Theorem 1.** The sum of an $n$-homomorphism with an $m$-homomorphism is an
> $\left(  n+m\right)  $-homomorphism.
>
> That is: Let $A$ and $B$ be two rings, with $B$ commutative. Let
> $f:A\rightarrow B$ be an $n$-homomorphism, and let $g:A\rightarrow B$ be an
> $m$-homomorphism. Then, $f+g$ is an $\left(  n+m\right)  $-homomorphism.

*Proof idea.* We must prove that every $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n+m+1}\in A$
satisfy
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+m+1}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}\ \ \prod
\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a
cycle of }\sigma}}\left(  f+g\right)  \left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots
a_{i_{k}}\right)  =0.
\end{align*}
We "simplify" the left hand side:
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+m+1}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}\underbrace{\prod
\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a
cycle of }\sigma}}\left(  f+g\right)  \left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots
a_{i_{k}}\right)  }_{\substack{=\sum\limits_{\substack{U\sqcup V=\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n+m+1\right\}  ;\\\sigma\left(  U\right)  =U\text{ and }
\sigma\left(  V\right)  =V}}\ \ \prod\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1}
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a cycle of }\sigma\text{ in }
U}}f\left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}}\right)  \cdot\prod
\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a
cycle of }\sigma\text{ in }V}}g\left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}
}\right)  \\\text{(the sum here is over all ways to decompose the set
}\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n+m+1\right\}  \\\text{into two disjoint subsets }U\text{
and }V\text{)}}}\\
& =\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+m+1}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}\sum
\limits_{\substack{U\sqcup V=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n+m+1\right\}  ;\\\sigma
\left(  U\right)  =U\text{ and }\sigma\left(  V\right)  =V}}\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \prod
\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a
cycle of }\sigma\text{ in }U}}f\left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}
}\right)  \cdot\prod\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots
,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a cycle of }\sigma\text{ in }V}}g\left(  a_{i_{1}
}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}}\right)  \\
& =\sum\limits_{U\sqcup V=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n+m+1\right\}  }\ \ \left(
\sum_{\alpha\text{ is a permutation of }U}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\alpha}
\prod\limits_{\substack{c=\left(  i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is
a cycle of }\alpha}}f\left(  a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}}\right)
\right)  \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot\left(  \sum_{\beta\text{ is a
permutation of }V}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\beta}\prod\limits_{\substack{c=\left(
i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{k}\right)  \\\text{is a cycle of }\beta}}g\left(
a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{k}}\right)  \right)  .
\end{align*}
In each addend of the outer sum, either $U$ has size $\geq n+1$ or $V$ has
size $\geq m+1$ (since otherwise, $U\sqcup V$ would have size $\leq n+m$), and
thus the respective parenthesized inner sum is $0$ (since $f$ is an
$n$-homomorphism and thus is easily seen to be an $n^{\prime}$-homomorphism
for all $n^{\prime}\geq n$, and likewise for $g$ and $m$). $\blacksquare$

[**EDIT:** Theorem 1 is part of Lemme 2.8 in [Raphaël Rouquier, *Caractérisation des caractères et Pseudo-caractères*, 1996](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1996.0083). However, the proof given there only works when $\left(n+m\right)!$ is invertible. It seems that my proof above is a polarization of Rouqier's proof, though.]

It is worth mentioning the "aspirational" properties of $n$-homomorphisms and
pseudo-characters, as they can be helpful. A pseudo-character of degree $n$
wishes to be the character of an $n$-dimensional representation of the
algebra. An $n$-homomorphism wishes to be a sum of $n$ ring homomorphisms. The
former wish can be fulfilled under certain restrictive conditions (see, e.g.,
§VII.7.3.4 in [Sophie Morel's notes cited
above](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Esmorel/rep_theory_notes.pdf)). I don't know when and to what extent the
latter can be fulfilled. However, if it can, then the Question would follow:
If $f:B\rightarrow C$ is a sum of $n$ (nonunital) ring homomorphisms, and if
$g$ is an $m$-homomorphism, then $f\circ g$ is an $nm$-homomorphism, as can be
easily proved using Theorem 1.